# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 Java excel files with unknown number of columns

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am making a program to read data from excel files as the above and store them in tables. I have managed to read all the data from excel files as a string and store them in a table.

```
ID  Name         Salary   

50  christine   2349000

43  paulina     1245874

54  laura       4587894

23  efi         3456457 

43  jim         4512878
```

**But** in my project I have several other files that have same cell that are blank as the above example

```
ID  Name            Salary     

50  christine       2349000

43  paulina         4587894

23  laura           3456457

43  jim             4512878
```

and when i ran the same program i get this exception :

```
SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
SQLState: 21S01
VendorError: 1136
```

The code for creating the table is the above:

```
private static String getCreateTable(Connection con, String tablename,
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> tableFields) {
    Iterator iter = tableFields.keySet().iterator();
    Iterator cells = tableFields.keySet().iterator();
    String str = "";
    String[] allFields = new String[tableFields.size()];
    int i = 0;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String fieldName = (String) iter.next();
        Integer fieldType = (Integer) tableFields.get(fieldName);

        switch (fieldType) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            str = fieldName + " INTEGER";
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            str = fieldName + " VARCHAR(255)";
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            str = fieldName + " INTEGER";
            break;
        default:
            str = "";
            break;
        }
        allFields[i++] = str;
    }
    try {
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        try {
            String all = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(
                    allFields, ",");
            String createTableStr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    + tablename + " (" + all + ")";

            System.out.println("Create a new table in the database");
            stmt.executeUpdate(createTableStr);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState:     " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError:  " + e.getErrorCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println( ((SQLException) e).getSQLState() );
        System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str;
}

private static void fillTable(Connection con, String fieldname,
        LinkedHashMap[] tableData) {
    for (int row = 0; row < tableData.length; row++) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> rowData = tableData[row];
        Iterator iter = rowData.entrySet().iterator();
        String str;
        String[] tousFields = new String[rowData.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) iter.next();
            Integer fieldType = (Integer) pairs.getValue();
            String fieldValue = (String) pairs.getKey();
            switch (fieldType) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                str = fieldValue;
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                str = "\'" + fieldValue + "\'";
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                str = fieldValue;
                break;
            default:
                str = "";
                break;
            }
            tousFields[i++] = str;
        }

        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String all = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(
                    tousFields, ",");
            String sql = "INSERT INTO " + fieldname + " VALUES (" + all
                    + ")";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("VendorError: " + e.getErrorCode());
        }

    }

    }
```

I am using HashMap to read all the data from excel files as string and store them in the table. But since I don't know each time the exact number of the column how I can fix it? I have read other posts that have specific number of columns and they use values('', ?, ?)` etc. How i would do it in my program?
The output that i get is the following:
[image]

Comment: please print `fieldname` and `all` variables and shows us the output

Comment: I put the image above.

Comment: the problem is at the second row of values : `43.0,paulina,laura,4587894.0` that means 4 values but you have only 3 columns

Comment: no. in the second row i have only ID and Name in my excel file and only these i want to store. The third row has only Name and Salary and no ID. How i would be able to store only the values that i have and leave blank in the second row the Salary and in the third row the ID? Is there a way for my program to skip the blanks as empty value?

Comment: I've updated my answer, pls check it out

Answer (score 0):

Most probably in `fieldname` variable you do not have the same amount of values as in `all` variable so basically what this means is that the number of column specified is not equal with the number of values

Also all strings must be escaped and surrounded by single quotes.

**EDIT:** after receiving some additional info from efoikonom :

If you have "blank" values you need to specify a default value ex:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table (
   ID,
   Name,
   Salary
 ) VALUES (
    43,
    'paulina',
    0
 ),(
    0,
    'laura',
    4587894.0
 )
```

**UPDATE:** Try this:

```
switch (fieldType) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        str = fieldValue;
        if(str.length() == 0){
          str = "0";
        }
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        str = "\'" + fieldValue + "\'";
        if(str.length() == 0){
          str = "'none'";
        }
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        str = fieldValue;
        if(str.length() == 0){
          str = "0";
        }
        break;
    default:
        str = "";
        break;
}
```

Comment: That's ok but in my program that's happen programmatically!I mean my program read each excel file and store the data in a table! That's why i am using hashmap to read all the data as string. I am not giving by hand each time the values. So, what you write is not useful for me because i am not giving every time the values. But the program read each values.

Comment: What i am asking is how the program would read the blank cells as empty cell and how would continue in the next one to store the value in the corresponding cell?

Comment: Its clear now what you want , its simple the empty cells enter the default case in your switch and using the column position in you case stored in variable `i` you can determine the empty cell to which column  it coresponds

Comment: i have rewritten the default case, pls check it out

Comment: I added them but I get exactly the same exception.

Comment: what is the values output ?

Comment: exactly the same as before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29648/discussion-between-stephan-and-efoikonom)